# JetBrains Fleet: Running Flutter project

Tags: flutter, jetbrains-fleet

I am trying out JetBrains Fleet. I was thinking to make a sample Flutter project in it. But not sure how to configure `run.json` for Flutter project.

It is pretty simple when it comes to terminal command: `flutter run --debug` or `flutter run --release`.

But I am struck at `run.json` file. Don't know what to write there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a run configuration of type command to achieve what you need.

you'll have to set `"type" : "command"`, then select your shell program (either `/bin/sh` or `powershell` depends on the platform you use).

Finally, you have to set args according to use case.

See this example (working for me on Windows) :

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
          "type": "command",
          "name": "run config debug",
          "program": "powershell", // For Windows
          "program": "/bin/sh", // For Linux or Mac
          "args": [
            "flutter", "run", "--debug"
          ],
        },

    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks. man. but what should I write in program instead of powershell if I use linux?

Comment: I think '/bin/sh' should work for Linux, it worked on my mac. I updated my answer

Comment: hmm... this does not work for me.  I've got this error: "/bin/sh: 0: cannot open flutter: No such file". Do you have some idea what is wrong?

Comment: @spajdo sh simply cannot find flutter, check path

Comment: @Jacouille but when I run flutter doctor in my terminal it run normally

Comment: @spajdo please open new Question and link it here, i'll try to help you

Comment: @Jacouille here is my question if you want to help me -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77661555/jetbrains-fleet-cannot-run-flutter-application