# JetBrains: Fleet cannot run Flutter application

Tags: flutter, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-fleet

I want to try JetBrains Fleet IDE for Flutter development. But I'm not able to run my application.
I tried to set run configuration which I found here on SO, but it is not working on in my case.
I'm running on Ubuntu.
[image]

When I run command flutter run --debug on terminal, everything is working.
I added flutter to path adding this to my ~/.bashrc file

```
export FLUTTER_HOME=~/DevTools/flutter
export PATH=${PATH}:$FLUTTER_HOME/bin
```

Can somebody to help me to find out the problem, why I can't run my app from Fleet?

Comment: Is flutter added properly in your path ? Or did you add it with export inside bash / zsh rc file ?

Comment: I added flutter to path adding this to my ~/.bashrc file
export FLUTTER_HOME=~/DevTools/flutter
export PATH=${PATH}:$FLUTTER_HOME/bin - I will add this to the question

Comment: Replace /bin/sh by /bin/bash in your fleet run config and it should work perfectly

Comment: Thx a lot. /bin/bash is working. But unfortunately Fleet is not ready for Flutter development. I will wait for JetBrains support :). Thx @Jacouille for your help.

Comment: Please vote for this request for Flutter-specific support: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/FL-10369/Support-for-Dart

Comment: @Andrey I voted for this sometime before. We will see, if they will add the support.